# npm/gulp/nodejs : Different files for production

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp

I have a gulp script that concatenate and minify my JavaScript.

With the `gulp-html-replace` plugin I can replace all my JS dependancies by the concatened file in my `index.html`.

I end up with a dev version (/dev/index.html), with all the single JS files included (easier for debugging) and a production version,with all JS concatened (/prod/index.html).

For now I have a config flag (in NodeJS) in a `config.js` file and I do the following :

```
res.render(((config.build === 'prod') ? './prod' : './dev') + 'myPage')
```

But I'm not really happy with this solution as it adds a lot of code and it's easy to forget to write this code.

- Is there a better solution ?
- Does this solution take place in Gulp
  (by havign a `gulp prod` and a `gulp dev` for example)
- Or does it take place in Node (by setting up a virtual directory for example)

I am new to this npm/gulp/node workflow and not sure of what belongs where

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I like to do it is by maintaining two separate versions for `index.html`.
`index-development.html` for dev environment and `index-production.html` for production environment.

The `index-development.html` includes all the scripts and css (non minified and concatenated) and `index-production.html` as minified and concatenated scripts and css links.

I construct `index.html` from gulp script.

By default the `index-development.html` will be deployed.
If I specify parameter `p` to the gulp script, it will deploy `index-production.html`

No need to update the file path of the file to be served in your `express router`.

First do

`npm install yargs`

In gulp, I include

`var argv = require('yargs').argv;`

Check if parameter `p` (`gulp -p`) is passed to the gulp (p for production) with

`var isProduction = argv.p;`

and then,

```
if(isProduction){
    taskSequence = ['combineControllers','combineServices','productionsIndex','startServer'];
} else{
    taskSequence = ['developmentIndex','startServer'];
}


gulp.task('default', taskSequence);
gulp.task('startServer', function(){
    exec('npm start', function (err, stdout, stderr) {
    console.log(stdout);
    console.log(stderr);
    cb(err);
  });
});
gulp.task('productionsIndex', function(done) {
    return gulp.src('./www/index-productions.html')
           .pipe(concat('index.html'))
           .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/'));
});

gulp.task('developmentIndex', function(done) {
    return gulp.src('./www/index-development.html')
           .pipe(concat('index.html'))
           .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/'));
});
```

This way, your `index.html` file will be constructed dynamically without having to change of the code in your `express` and you can serve it like

`res.render('index');`

if you want to user `myPage.html` everywhere, just replace `index.html` and `index` in the code above with `myPage.html` and `myPage`.

EDIT:

To start your application in development environment, simply run `gulp`

To start your application in production  environment, simply run `gulp -p`

Simple!

Answer (score 1):

in your app initialization process you can set the path of your views.

```
app.set('views', process.cwd() + ((config.build === 'prod') ? '/prod' : '/dev'));
```

Now you can call the render function like this:

```
res.render('myPage');
```